# Listview with headers. SeparatedListAdapter using database data crash

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a ListView with headers based on a number of predefined categories.

I am using [Jeff Sharkey's separating lists with headers](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) as a basis. The classes and XML are identical except for SimpleAdapter. The difference is my data is coming from a local SQLite database. The code crashes when I switch out of the view. Any ideas why this could be? Error and code below.

```
07-15 14:58:44.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:149)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at com.XYZ.XYZ.SeparatedListAdapter.getView(SeparatedListAdapter.java:94)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1256)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1224)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1499)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-15 14:58:44.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`Category.java` - my equivalent to SimpleAdapter from Starkey's tutorial:

```
package com.XYZ.ipantrylite;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Category extends Activity {

    public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";
    public final static String ITEM_CAPTION = "caption";

    public SeparatedListAdapter adapter;

    private static final String TAG = "Category";

    public Map<String,?> createItem(String title, String caption) {
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
        item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);
        item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
//  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
        super.onCreate(icicle); 

        // create our list and custom adapter
        adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);
        fillData();

        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.setContentView(list);
    }

    private void fillData()
    {
        String[] types = new String[] { 
                "Baby Food", 
                "Baking Supplies", 
                "Beverages", 
                "Dairy Products & Eggs",
                "Fresh Produce, Fruits & Vegetables",
                "Canned, Dried, Frozen Goods",
                "Grains, Cereals, Breads, Pasta",
                "Herbs & Spices",
                "Misc Canned Goods",
                "Oils & Fats",
                "Prepackaged Foods",
                "Protein, Meat, Fish",
                "Snacks & Sweets",
                "Soups, Sauces, & Gravies",
                "Toiletries"};

        for(int i = 0; i < types.length - 1; i++) 
        {           
            Cursor c = managedQuery(PantryItemsProviderLite.CONTENT_URI, null, "TYPE = '"+types[i]+"'", null, "name desc");

            startManagingCursor(c);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                c.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), PantryItemsProviderLite.CONTENT_URI); 
                String[] from = new String[] { PantryItemsProviderLite.NAME};
                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textName};

                SimpleCursorAdapter items = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.items_row_cat, c, from, to);
                adapter.addSection(types[i], items);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        clearData();
        Log.d("","on Pause called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fillData();
        Log.d("","on Resume called");
    }

    public void clearData(){
        adapter.headers.clear();
        adapter.sections.clear();
    }
}
```

Line of code referred to in debugger at crash:

```
Line 94
if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using the updated SeperatedListAdapter code from http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/source/browse/main/src/com/joelapenna/foursquared/widget/SeparatedListAdapter.java, then `onPause` I use `adapter.clear()`, then `onResume` I refill. I notify of data change in fillData loop. Working.